# How do i show a context menu when right click on a Pane or an ImageView in javaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am trying to show a context menu i created, when i right click on a pane or an image view ((on Context Menu Requested)). The problem is they don't seem to have a **setContextMenue** method, unlike labels and buttons...etc. How can associate a context menu to a node that doesn't seem to accept context menus?

```
@FXML
Button button1, button2;

@FXML
Pane mainPane;

@FXML
ImageView image;
private void initContextMenu() {
    final ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
    final MenuItem item1 = new MenuItem("open a file");
    final MenuItem item2 = new MenuItem("quit");

    contextMenu.getItems().addAll(item1, item2);

    // not possible
    image.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
    // possible
    button1.setContextMenu(contextMenu)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do

```
image.setOnContextMenuRequested(e -> 
    contextMenu.show(image, e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY()));
```

Comment: I tried -> contextMenu.show(imgWidnow.getScene().getWindow() and it functions properly, but now the menu's position is fixed in the middle of the window.

Comment: i actually solved it like this. Thank you though                                                                                             imgWidnow.setOnContextMenuRequested(event -> {
            contextMenu.setY(event.getScreenY());
            contextMenu.setX(event.getScreenX());
            contextMenu.show(imgWidnow.getScene().getWindow());
        });

Comment: @RafatRefai Never seen that behavior before. The `show(Node, double, double)` method has always worked for me. What OS / JDK version are you using? (To make it close on lost focus, try `contextMenu.setAutoHide(true);`.)

Comment: I can confirm `show(Window)` after explicitly `setX` and `setY` works rather than `show(Node, double, double)`. I'm on JDK 8u241 in macOS 10.15.2.