# Does right-clicking on a JavaFX Node generate a `ContextMenuEvent` independent of the platform?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am trying to create a `ContextMenu` that appears when a user right-clicks on a Node in JavaFX, I found the `setOnContextMenuRequested` method in `Node` which is used in [this example](http://o7planning.org/en/11115/javafx-contextmenu-tutorial) and recommended in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41199786/how-do-i-show-a-context-menu-when-right-click-on-a-pane-or-an-imageview-in-javaf). However, in the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/ContextMenuEvent.html) it says that the keyboard or mouse sequence to trigger the required `ContextMenuEvent` is platform dependent.

Does anyone know whether right-clicking on a `Node` will platform independently generate a `ContextMenuEvent`? I wouldn't normally ask this considering the documentation clearly says that this event is platform dependent, however I wanted to check whether there is some other information I am missing considering I am yet to see a warning in the examples I am reading and it didn't break when I tested it on Windows or Linux.

Here's an example of how I want to use it:

```
VBox root = new VBox();

ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

Circle circle = new Circle();
circle.setRadius(70);

root.getChildren().addAll(circle);

circle.setOnContextMenuRequested(
    new EventHandler<ContextMenuEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ContextMenuEvent contextMenuEvent) {
            contextMenu.show(root, contextMenuEvent.getScreenX(),
                    contextMenuEvent.getScreenY());
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: On touch devices youre not going to do a right click but you can still request the contextmenu. That said, of you want to handle only a right click, register a Event for right click. If you want to handle a contextmenu request, register a contextmenu Event.

Comment: You can use mouse event for Right Clicking and ContextMenuRequested for touch screens.

Comment: Ahhhhh, thanks!! That is an interesting insight! I definitely want to be able to get the context menu to appear regardless of the device so these comments reinforce that ContextMenuRequested is the functionality I am looking for.